# Will there be another season of DanMachi after the second season?

Tags: danmachi

After the second season of *DanMachi* I have waited for the next season, but unfortunately I’m still waiting. So I would like to know if there will be another season, or if I will have to read the manga scans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anime is currently up to *four* seasons, [with a fifth season having been announced in November 2023](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2023-11-04/is-it-wrong-to-try-to-pick-up-girls-in-a-dungeon-anime-gets-5th-season/.204100) to air at an unspecified date in the future. I can only assume that whatever service you were watching the anime through didn't have the third and fourth seasons for some reason. Sadly, I can't recommend a place to watch seasons 3 or 4, but I'm sure you can find one.